# L-function terminology

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of two number fields. Denote by $\mathfrak f$ the conductor of $E/F$ and let $\chi$ be the primitive Hecke Grossencharacter mod $\mathfrak f$ associated to the non-trivial character of the abelian group $Gal(E/F)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

In the literature about L-functions I encountered the following statement: Let $L(s)$ be the usual L-function of the quadratic character of $\mathbb A^\times_F$ corresponding to $E/F$. Does this mean that $L(s)=L(s,\chi)$ is the Hecke L-function of $\chi$?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you! Is the proof long? If yes, can you recommend a reference explaining these kind of things?

Comment: I don't think there's a proof - I would just consider this to be the definition of "the quadratic character corresponding to $E/F$".

Comment: All right, thanks!

Comment: @WillSawin I think it is a Galois character associated to $E/F$ and we need a bit of class field theory to show that (through the Artin map) it is a Hecke character and find its conductor.

Comment: @reuns Sure, but this class field theory is assumed already in the first paragraph of the question.